# How to show only top level menu name in Superfish

Tags: 7, navigation

As seen "Departmental Information" is first level sub menu under top level "Staff Menu". But I want only to display "Staff Menu" and it should expand only on hover. **How to do it?**

I've tried all the options in Superfish block settings.

I've added this code to generate the html:

```
$block = block_load('superfish', '1');
$menus = render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
```

[image]

[image]

Otherwise it's working fine and when I hover over "Departmental Information" it does expand as in this picture:

[image: Second level onwards working properly]

Comment: Have you added 'jQuery Easing plugin' into library folder?

Comment: @NikhilBanait yes

Comment: I assume you have "Staff Menu" set as Block-Title, because it's not shown in the admin-menu screenshot? If not, you have probably set this menu item to "Show as expanded"....?